# Не получается выполнить поисковой запрос в гугле через javascript в tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, бот, tampermonkey

Я пытаюсь реализовать автоматический поисковой запрос в гугле ( или других поисковых систем) через javascript в tampermonkey. У меня получилось присвоить какое-либо значение поисковой строке ( input ) и вроде все шло по плану, но в один момент я понял, что не смотря на наличие какого-либо текста в imput сам поисковик никак не воспринимает его. Однако, если после набора текста через .value = "текст" или любой другой способ ввода информации навести мышку на обьект imput и самому ввести любой знак поисковая система начинает понимать введенный текст, но самому нажимать не вариант, ведь нам нужна автоматизация. Я пробовал симулировать нажатие клавиши через jQuery а именно используя .keypress(), но у меня ничего не вышло. Я пробовал много других вариантов, например ввод текста после фокусирования на элемент используя jQuery

```
  $( '#pole_vvoda' ).on({
    'focus': function() {
        $( this ).val("Мой запрос");

    },
```

Но это не дало успехов. Пожалуйста, помогите с проблемой и если есть возможность напишите код, который будет выполнять поисковой запрос, например в гугле. Спасибо.

Comment: если у тебя что-то `не нажимается(работает)`, то используй `console.log('сейчас должно происходить, что-то');`, потом после действия\в нём: `console.log('действие происходит');` // это всё можно считать как часть "учения", ибо попытка - не пытка, и лучше узнать - чем предполагать, пример этому: '2'-1 и '2'+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я попробовал с [гоголом](https://google.ru), в [этом расширении](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-exec/caeimpdeapdimekjkkkggpibnlijlnka)

```js
$('.gLFyf.gsfi').val('asd');
$('input.gNO89b').click();
```

(не знаю когда там эти *селекторы красивые* обновятся, но) у меня сработало

Во вторых, тампермонкей (как по мне) подходит для задач плана: `[1.] вкинул код [2.] забыл ([3. обновил])`, ибо не user\dev френдли.
А если хочешь распространять свой код, то смотри уже в строну расширений, там не такой уж и тёмный лес..

Посему, вот [расширение](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-javascript-and-css/nbhcbdghjpllgmfilhnhkllmkecfmpld), ибо `критикуешь(tm) - предлагай`, попробуй в нём следующий код, только не забудь свежий jq подключить и выбрать его у скрипта-сайта (по hover'у на опции, над редактором, скрин ниже)

```js
window.onload=()=>{
    $('.gLFyf.gsfi').val('asd');
    $('input.gNO89b').click();
};
```

Должно получиться следующим образом:
[image: скрин расширения]

Comment: хоть бы отписал, как у тебя дела, я не знаю)

Comment: @2ip мы могли и мы посмотрели еще [один сайт](https://znanija.com/signup?entry=1), на нём нужно использовать `new KeyboardEvent` в `.dispatchEvent()`, тогда сработает проверятор емаила и кнопка будет доступна

Comment: Хорошо, попробую использовать это. Спасибо вам.

Comment: @2ip это после `.val()` используется, пиши если проблемы будут

Comment: Я попытался использовать .dispatchEvent(), к сожалению ничего из этого не вышло, перебрал разные способы и остановился на этом :[ссылка](https://ibb.co/BTscTcR), в некоторых случаях скрипт просто выводил True в консоль, но ничего не происходило, кнопка все еще серая

Comment: @2ip глаза(( 
1. Табуляция это важно
2. Почему на 2,4,9 у тебя натив, когда подключен Jq? разберись с jq, делай как человек, пожалуйста 
3. Использовать var - прошлый век

Comment: не могли бы вы привести пример использования new KeyboardEvent в .dispatchEvent(), у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы это все работало

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("sg-input sg-input--full-width")[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress',{'key':'a'})); ` Я попытался использовать это, но ничего не вышло

Comment: @2ip [q](https://github.com/b5414/keystrokeEmulator/blob/master/main.js)

Comment: всеравно не работает, может там защита какая-то стоит?

Comment: @2ip защита от тебя)) пробуй с [этим](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-exec/caeimpdeapdimekjkkkggpibnlijlnka) `$('input.sg-input').val('text').kes();`

Comment: У вас получалось сделать эту кнопку активной? Может это нельзя реализовать на js?

Comment: Еще я нашел [этот](http://utyatnishna.ru/info/22830/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript) метод, похоже он был написан именно для случая, когда кнопка проверяет факт ввода символов клавиатурой в input. Только вот я не могу применить его для конкретной ситуации с тем сайтом

Comment: Спасибо что помогали мне, я нашел решение этой проблемы, надо было просто сделать это : `document.getElementsByClassName("ваш_input")[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true}));`

Comment: @2ip _ отлично)